# Aframe MTL isn't loaded correctly

Tags: aframe

Aframe version 5.0.0

In my scene I have an obj file (a cat) and I've applied an mtl file to it, but the mtl don't works at all, the object remains white, and If I check it with the inspector the object became all black.
[image: senza titolo 2]

This is the code:

```
<a-scene>
            <a-assets>
                  ...
                <a-asset-item id="crate-obj" src="@asset('images/cat.obj')"></a-asset-item>
                <a-asset-item id="crate-mtl" src="@asset('images/cat.mtl')"></a-asset-item>
                  ...
            </a-assets>
                 ...
               <a-obj-model src="#crate-obj" mtl="#crate-mtl"></a-obj-model>
                ...
        </a-scene>
```

I think that the path of my mtl it's correct...
**@ asset** points to the assets folder of my project.

The warning that chrome inspector shows is:
*components:obj-model:warn Material component properties are ignored when a .MTL is provided +0ms*

I've searched the warning and the problem on the web but I didn't find anything...

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you try [this](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/models.html#i-don%E2%80%99t-see-textures) ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski yes I checked the link but I've already a relative path ..

Comment: not exactly the anwser, but I'd recommend trying to convert your model to the `gltf` format ? It's designed specifically for webgl.

Comment: Does updating to A-Frame 0.8.2 solve your issue?

Comment: Provide a full runnable example if you can. glitch.com is a good option.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos Update to aframe 0.8.2 gives me other problems so I can't update it unfortunately. Asap I'll provide a runnable example

Comment: Older versions of A-Frame are not maintained. I recommend upgrading to benefit from bug fixes and performance improvements.

Comment: I've solved the problem. .obj and .mtl are not enough for the model to work. It is necessary to include, in the same directory of the two files, also the .jpg or the .png of the texture that it's referenced by the MTL file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the texture map files referenced from the MTL are accesible on the appropriate path (Look for 404 errors in the network panel) Most likely they have to be served from the same directory as
your OBJ and MTL.

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer here and on github!